# Sails.js - How to do a native query on a model that have an attribute of array type?

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

I build a web app using sails.js and my database is mongo.

This is my model - Conversation:

```
module.exports = {

  tableName: 'conversations',

  attributes: {

    members: {
      type: 'array',
      collection: 'user'
    },

    status: {
      type: 'boolean',
      defaultsTo: true,
      required: true
    }
  }

};
```

As you can see above, I have an array of members (User model). 
However, in the database each document of the Conversations collection save **without** "members" field but Sails js created a new collection "conversation_members__user_members_user" - for the "join" I guess.

When I use "find" to get a document from "Conversations" collection I get this:

```
{  
   "status": true,
   "createdAt": "2016-08-03T18:55:03.993Z",
   "updatedAt": "2016-08-03T18:55:04.016Z",
   "id": "57a23e079983469c1a20810a"
}
```

Of course, **without** "members" (because sails saved them at another collection).

### **My Problem:**

When I tried to use a native query on the "members" with this code I got no results:

```
var members = ["579d083a38db0c7c07860819", "579d088fbab7ec0c0be80c77"];

Conversation.native(function(err, collection) {

   collection.find({ members.id: {'$all':members }}).toArray(function(err, results) {

    if (err) return res.serverError(err);
    return res.ok(results);
  });
});
```

I think the problem was that there is no "members" field in Conversation document so it make sense that there are no results.

So, if I want to do a native query on the "members" (because sails queries are not enough) -
how can I do it? 
Or how to also add "members" field to the Conversation document?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Change your `User model` to contain `conversations` attribute:

```
conversations: {
      collection: 'Conversation',
      via: 'members',
      dominant: true
    }
```

Then change `Conversation` model to

```
members: {
      collection: 'User',
      via: 'conversations'
    }
```

You can then add a new user to a conversation

```
var criteria = {id: '12345'};
User.findOne(criteria).exec(function(err, user) {
  if(err) // handle error

  user.conversations.add({id: 'the id of conversation to which you need to add the user'});

  user.save(function(err) {});
});
```

To retrieve the members of a conversation, You can use the good old populate method waterline provides.

```
Conversation.findOne(criteria).populate('members').exec(function(err, results){
// do something with your result.
});
```

You can retrieve the conversations a user is member of using:

```
User.findOne(criteria).populate('conversations').exec(function(err, results){
// your desired result
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But if I want to find a conversation when all the members are exactly "X" and "Y" - How I can i do it?

Comment: You can do it by adding a criteria for populating `Conversation.findOne(criteria).populate('members', {id: idArrayOfUsers}).exec(function(err, results){
// do something with your result.
});`

Comment: Thanks again but according to my check this line will populate user if her id is in idArrayOfUsers. I want to find a Conversation by members id...